# pytest 5.x+ upgrade and use a command line flag to run/skip decorated tests

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest, pytest-fixtures

I'm trying to upgrade from pytest 4.x to something newer. However, I'm running into issues where `pytest.config` was removed and I'm not sure how to accommodate the new syntax. Specifically, I'm trying to specify a command line flag that can run or skip specific decorated tests depending on whether or not the flag is present.

This is how it works in pytest 4.x.

```py
# common.py
integration = pytest.mark.skipif(
    not pytest.config.getoption('--integration', False),
)
```

Then, elsewhere in the tests..

```py
# test_something.py 
from .common import integration 

@integration
def test_mytest():
    1 == 1

@integration
def test_other_mytest():
    2 == 2
```

In newer versions of pytest, the above fails with:

`AttributeError: module 'pytest' has no attribute 'config'`

In pytest 5.x+, how can I achieve the same result as above - how can I pass in flag to pytest and run/skip certain tests based on that flag? Preferably, it would be nice to decorate them as in the example, as I have a lot of tests using the decorator syntax and it could be difficult to update them all. Any advice is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use a [custom marker](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/example/markers.html?highlight=option) and the existing `-m` command line option. If you redefine your `integration` decorator like this:

```
import pytest

integration = pytest.mark.integration

@integration
def test1():
    pass

def test2():
    pass
```

And define the `integration` marker in `pytest.ini`:

```
[pytest]
markers =
  integration
```

Then you can run all tests:

```
$ pytest -v
========================================= test session starts =========================================
platform linux -- Python 3.11.6, pytest-7.2.2, pluggy-1.0.0 -- /usr/bin/python3
cachedir: .pytest_cache
rootdir: /home/lars/tmp/python, configfile: pytest.ini
collected 2 items

test_skip.py::test1 PASSED                                                                      [ 50%]
test_skip.py::test2 PASSED                                                                      [100%]

========================================== 2 passed in 0.00s ==========================================
```

Or only integration tests:

```
$ pytest -v -m integration
========================================= test session starts =========================================
platform linux -- Python 3.11.6, pytest-7.2.2, pluggy-1.0.0 -- /usr/bin/python3
cachedir: .pytest_cache
rootdir: /home/lars/tmp/python, configfile: pytest.ini
collected 2 items / 1 deselected / 1 selected

test_skip.py::test1 PASSED                                                                      [100%]

=================================== 1 passed, 1 deselected in 0.00s ===================================
```

Or only non-integration tests:

```
$ pytest -v -m 'not integration'
========================================= test session starts =========================================
platform linux -- Python 3.11.6, pytest-7.2.2, pluggy-1.0.0 -- /usr/bin/python3
cachedir: .pytest_cache
rootdir: /home/lars/tmp/python, configfile: pytest.ini
collected 2 items / 1 deselected / 1 selected

test_skip.py::test2 PASSED                                                                      [100%]

=================================== 1 passed, 1 deselected in 0.00s ===================================
```

This meets your goal of not having to update all your tests.

Comment: Thank you for your thoughts on this. Looks like a nice simple solution.